# Binary search tree<TKey, TValue> height

Tags: c#, binary-search-tree

I am about to implement a good binary search tree. Does anyone know how to calculate Binarysearchtree TKey, TValue height? Thanks!
Now I used this to get the height of any BST tree. but it does not seem to work with in this specific case.

```
     public int Height()
    {
        return height(root);
    }
    protected int height(Node tree)
    {

        if (tree == null)
            return -1;
        int lefth = height(tree.left);
        int righth = height(tree.right);

        if (lefth > righth)
            return lefth + 1;
        else
            return righth + 1;


    }
```

Comment: I think you have to recursively iterate the entire tree to find the height out.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! The question etiquette here is to show what you tried (demonstrate that you at least did a bit of research) and paste your code that you need help with. If you want premade solutions, this is not really the right place for that.

Answer (score 0):

You do know that you already have one?

`System.Collections.Generic.SortedSet<T>` is a [red-black tree](https://www.cs.auckland.ac.nz/software/AlgAnim/red_black.html) (height-balanced).

If that's not enough, you've also got the [C5 Collections Library](https://www.itu.dk/research/c5/) which gives you other red-black tree implementations:

- `TreeSet<T>`

  > represents a set of items using a balanced red-black tree; see section 13.10.
  >   Item access by index or by item value takes time *O(log n)*, and item insertion
  >   and item deletion take time *O(log n)* amortized. A tree set does not allow
  >   duplicates, so the property `AllowsDuplicates` is false.
- `TreeBag<T>`

  > represents a bag, or multiset, of items using a balanced red-black tree.
  >   Item access by index or by item value takes time *O(log n)*, and item insertion
  >   and item deletion take time *O(log n)* amortized.
  >
  > A tree bag allows duplicates, so the property `AllowsDuplicates` is true,
  >   and only one representative for each item equivalence class is stored, so
  >   `DuplicatesByCounting` is true.
- `TreeDictionary<K,V>`

  > represents a dictionary of (key,value) pairs, or entries, using an ordered
  >   balanced red-black binary tree. Entry access, entry deletion, and entry insertion
  >   take time *O(log n)*. Enumeration of the keys, values or entries of a tree
  >   dictionary follow the key order, as determined by the key comparer.

Go to town, but why re-invent the wheel unless you really want to?

Comment: Well I know this but I am not quiet sure that I can use it. :-) School task.

Answer (score 0):

private static int getHeight(BTreeNode n){

```
if(n == null)
    return 0;

int lHeight = getHeight(n.left);
int rheight = getHeight(n.right);

int height = 1+Math.max(lHeight,rheight);

return height;
```

}